# How to use "mobx" in ReactJS-PhpStorm ? Thanks

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm

These "import" do not work in PhpStorm. How import 'observer' from mobx ?

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
```

or

```
import { decorate, computed, observable, action } from 'mobx';
```

Comment: according to https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html, you need importing it as `import { observer } from "mobx-react";` (or as `import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"`, depending on react bindings package you choose [when installing](https://mobx.js.org/installation.html#installation)). What do you mean saying it doesn't work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena, mobx related methods don't work

Comment: what do you mean?